# I need to shift objects of an array around if they meet a certain condition in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I have an array where I need to take all of the null values (int this case I'm considering all the null values that -1 null) and I need to move them to the end of the array, and the organize the array in ascending order, once all of the null values are moved to the end. The array is

```
int [] array = {23,2,34,345,6,1,45,78,-1,-1,-1,-1,61,-1}
```

I'm not really sure where I need to start, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: no i really don't know where to start, I know I could just switch the 61 and the first -1, but I want it to work for all instances not just this one array.

Comment: If you were using a `List<Integer>` rather than an `int[]` you could do this easily using a `Comparator`. Look at the docs for `Arrays`, `Collections` and `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to move all '-1's at the end of your array. You can use a comparator for that.

```
    Integer[] tab = {23,2,34,345,6,1,45,78,-1,-1,-1,-1,61,-1};

    Arrays.sort(tab, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            return a == -1 ? 1 : b == -1 ? -1 : 0;
        }

    });
```

Note that you have to wrap your int array in an Integer array (like in the previous example) to be able to use a comparator.

You may want to take a look at the Comparator [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Given an array such as:

```
int[] array = {23, 2, 34, 345, 6, 1, 45, 78, -1, -1, -1, -1, 61, -1}
```

You could it like this:

1. **Sort the array in non-decreasing order**: Check the `Arrays.sort()` ([docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29)) method.

   ```
   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 6, 23, 34, 45, 61, 78, 345]
   ```
2. **Find the first element in the sorted array that is greater than `-1`**: Loop through the `array` elements, stop when you find an element such that `array[i] > -1`, and keep its index (let's call it `start`).

   ```
   start = 5
   ```
3. **Copy the elements greater than `-1` to the first positions in the array**: Loop through the array, from `0` to `array.length - start`, doing `array[i] = array[i + start]`.

   ```
   [1, 2, 6, 23, 34, 45, 61, 78, 345, 34, 45, 61, 78, 345]
   ```
4. **Fill the rest of the array with `-1`**: Use `Arrays.fill(array, fromIndex, toIndex, val)` ([docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int[],%20int,%20int,%20int%29)) to fill the array with `-1`, from `array.length - start` to `array.length`.

   ```
   [1, 2, 6, 23, 34, 45, 61, 78, 345, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.reverseOrder() in Arrays.sort(), but, Collections.reverseOrder() function takes a class object hence you will need to make your int array as an Integer array where Integer is a wrapper class. the following code will work for you,take a look:-

```
Integer [] array = {23,2,34,345,6,1,45,78,-1,-1,-1,-1,61,-1};
Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder());
```